# How to detect a file modifications with TFS?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, version-control, winmerge

It seems that when I use a tool (such as winmerge) to update my codebase... my Visual Studio Team System (VSTS) integration with Team Foundation Server (TFS) doesn't seem to pick it up.

How do I know which files to check out and check back in? Is there something I am missing? Is this a feature that isn't part of VSTS & TFS?

Comment: @Mitch Wheat I think the question contains all the info.

Comment: thx for taking the time to add that comment on a 4 yr old question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, this is probably because the files have not yet been checked out.  If you do that first before running your update, TFS will see those changes.

Second, you can use TFS Power Tools (available from MS) to review local repository for changes that are not recognized.  If there are found differences, power toys resets the status of the file so Pending Changes window sees the change.  this does not require you to check-out the files, it will do that for you if there are differences.

Pretty nifty.

Power Tools for 2008 is here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15836

and you are looking for the "Online" command:

"Online Command - Use the online command to create pending edits on writable files that do not have pending edits."

Comment: I don't necessarily know which files need to be checked out because I am doing a mass winmerge with many files.

I am basically trying to merge one branch of code into another branch of code using winmerge.

Ahh TFS Power Tools!

Comment: check them all out but again, it doesn't matter if you check them out if you install Power Tools - it doesn't care if they are checked out or not, it simply looks for differences between your local repository and the source.

Comment: Yes, you want the TF power toys. Specifically, "tfpt online /adds /deletes . /r".

Comment: When I try "tfpt online /adds /deletes . /r" it says "Unable to determine the workspace" :S

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are applying changes across an entire project, outside of VS.
You will have to check-out the complete project first, then apply the changes and check back in. Unmodified files will not be actually checked-in, AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

Your question sound like as if you have not installed the Team Foundation Server Client.

If you have installed the Visual Studio Team System edition you are able to connect with the Team Foundation Server. But to have the integration working you need to install the Team Foundation Server Client as well.

After having done this your Visual Studio should inform you in case of file changes and then automatically check out the files.